# Filtering a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a square matrix. I need to analyse every diagonal and check whether there are at least n=threshold adjacent elements grater than 0 in each diagonal. If the number of adjacent positive elements is smaller than threshold, then I must set these elements to 0.

I've just written two functions. One of them extracts subsequent diagonals, counts positive elements and sets appropriate elements in the diagonal to 0. The second one insert changed diagonal to the matrix.

I've tried to correct this code many times, but I still have the same problem. Could anybody help me? Thanks for advance.

```
function [ filteredMatrix ] = filterMatrix2( matrix, threshold )

sum = 0; %counts adjacent numbers that are > 0
matrixDimension = length(matrix);
filteredMatrix = matrix;

%a diagonal number is in range [ -dimension+1 ; dimension-1 ]
for k = (-matrixDimension+1) : (matrixDimension-1)
    diagonal = diag(matrix, k); %get next diagonal
    diagonalLength = length(diagonal); 
    sum=0;

    %if a diagonal length is shorter than threshold, 
    %than i must set all elements to 0
    if ( diagonalLength < threshold )
        diagonal = zeros(diagonalLength, 1);
    else
        for x = 1 : diagonalLength
            if diagonal(x) > 0
                sum = sum+1;
            else
               if ( sum < threshold )
                   %set previous elements to 0
                    for y = x-sum : x      
                        diagonal(y) = 0;
                    end
                    sum = 0;
               end
            end
        end
    end
    filteredMatrix = setDiagonal2(filteredMatrix, k, diagonal); (line 33)
end

end
```

2nd function:

```
function [ changedMatrix ] = setDiagonal2( matrix, numberOfDiagonal, diagonal )

  changedMatrix = matrix;
  diagonalLength = length(diagonal);

  numberOfRows = size(matrix,1);
  %numberOfColumns = size(matrix,2);

  %determin index of the first element of the diagonal
  if numberOfDiagonal < 0
    firstIndex = 1 - numberOfDiagonal;
  else
    firstIndex = 1 + numberOfDiagonal*numberOfRows;
  end 

 changedMatrix(firstIndex : numberOfRows+1 : diagonalLength) = diagonal; 
  (line 15)

 end
```

And this is a problem:

> > In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
> >
> > Error in setDiagonal2 (line 15)
> >
> > changedMatrix(firstIndex : numberOfRows+1 : diagonalLength) = diagonal;
> >
> > Error in filterMatrix2 (line 33)
> >
> > filteredMatrix = setDiagonal2(filteredMatrix, k, diagonal);

Comment: You can use the function `keyboard` just before line 15, this will give you access to the keyboard, then you can test the size of `diagonal` and 
`firstIndex : numberOfRows+1 : diagonalLength`. You can also see the values, and check if they are correct (they probably aren't)

Comment: Thanks, I've just solved it.